# Kalman filter always predicting origin

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, prediction, kalman-filter

I am learning kalman filters for the purpose of trajectory prediction. Right now, I am able to track the ball. For my first practical attempt with prediction and kalman filter, I used an example of drawing lines as given here:

[Is there any example of cv2.KalmanFilter implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012038/is-there-any-example-of-cv2-kalmanfilter-implementation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is the complete code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videoplayback (1).mp4')
loHue = 0
loSaturation = 50
loValue = 50
high_hue = 0
high_saturation = 255
high_value = 255
flag_for_center = 1
def low_hue(x):
    global loHue
    loHue = x 

#def low_saturation(x):
    #global loSaturation
    #loSaturation = x

#def low_value(x):
    #global loValue
    #loValue = x

def upper_hue (x):
    global high_hue
    high_hue = x

#def upper_saturation(x):
    #global high_saturation
    #high_saturation= x

#def upper_value(x):
    #global high_value
    #high_value = x

cv2.namedWindow('Trackbars', flags=cv2.WINDOW_OPENGL)
cv2.resizeWindow('Trackbars', 500, 30)
cv2.moveWindow('Trackbars', 500, 600)
cv2.createTrackbar('loHue', 'Trackbars', 0, 180, low_hue)
#cv2.createTrackbar('loSaturation', 'Trackbars', 0, 255, low_saturation)
#cv2.createTrackbar('lowValue', 'Trackbars', 0, 255, low_value)
cv2.createTrackbar('upperHue', 'Trackbars', 0, 180, upper_hue)
#cv2.createTrackbar('upperSat', 'Trackbars', 0, 255, upper_saturation)
#cv2.createTrackbar('upperValue', 'Trackbars', 0, 255, upper_value)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('loHue', 'Trackbars', 5)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('upperHue', 'Trackbars', 30)

frame_count = 0
measure = []
predicted = []

while(True):




_, image = cap.read()
frame_count = frame_count + 1
image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (3, 3), 2)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_limit = np.array([loHue,loSaturation,loValue])
upper_limit = np.array([high_hue,high_saturation,high_value])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_limit, upper_limit)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
#b,g,r = cv2.split(res)
#b = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(b,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
#   cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,20)
#g = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(g,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
#   cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11,20)
#r = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(r,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
#   cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,20)    
#res = cv2.merge((b,g,r))           
erode_element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
dilate_element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
erosion = cv2.erode(mask, erode_element, iterations = 1)
erosion = cv2.erode(erosion, erode_element, iterations = 1)
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion, dilate_element, iterations = 1)
dilation = cv2.dilate(dilation, dilate_element, iterations = 1)
copy_dilation = dilation.copy()

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(copy_dilation, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, 
 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
center = None

if len(contours) > 0:
    c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
    x,y = center

    measure = np.array([[np.float32(x)],[np.float32(y)]])
    #print(measure)
    #if (radius>10):
    #   cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (0, 255, 255), -2)
    #   cv2.circle(image, center, 3, (0,0,255),-1)
kalman = cv2.KalmanFilter(4,2)

kalman.transitionMatrix = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)
kalman.measurementMatrix = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]], np.float32)
kalman.processNoiseCov = np.array([[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]],np.float32) * 0.03

#while(True):
kalman.correct(measure)
update_predicted_state = kalman.predict()
predicted.append((int(update_predicted_state[0]), int(update_predicted_state[1])))
for i in range(len(predicted)-1):
    cv2.imshow('tracking', image)
    cv2.moveWindow('tracking', 150, 150)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.moveWindow('mask', 700, 150)
    cv2.circle(image, (predicted[i][0], predicted[i + 1][1]), int(radius), (0, 255, 255), -2)
k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
if k ==27:
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The issue is that the predicted values are all zero. As a result, I am getting a quarter circle at the top left corner. Any explanation ?
BTW, the video on which I am running this thing is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcFVOzQ1Oqc

The tracking part is working good and I am able to track the ball. However the problem starts with this line:

`kalman.correct(measure)`

When I tried to print it, it was all zero

```
[[0.]
[0.]
[0.]
[0.]]
```

Is it because I have not considered control matrix here ? Or is it just because of the odd bouncing of the ball ?

As you might have guessed it, the frame rates are awfully low.

Thank you.

Comment: I see several problems here... 1) you intialize the kalman filter in a loop... it should be intialized outside... 2) you do correct and then predict, it is the other way around... first predict, even if you do not use it and then correct... 3) ideally you should use the kalman filter to predict the position of the ball in the next frame, for instance, what happens if you get 2 contours?  4) unless the ball starts in 0,0, you should add a pre-state with the initial measurement

Comment: But the example from the other question does correction first followed by prediction. Please check it out. Also my x and y positions are given by center and my initial state is not zero.

Comment: It should be prediction and then correction, some values are set internaly and may differ from the initial one, then you call the correction with your measurement that will set other values inside... even if you are not using the resulting values of each of them it is recommended to call them. Even if you do not start in 0,0 the kalman filter will catch up after 3-5 frames. Take a look to this [c++ implementation](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/01/kalman-filter-implementation-tracking.html) and the results. Look how it jumps to the result after starting in 0,0

Comment: I just pulled out the KF initialisation from the loop and now its working! The circle is no longer at the origin and is following the ball. Seems everything is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

*There is a better explanation here:* [KalmanFilter always predict 0,0 in first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327207/kalmanfilter-always-predict-0-0-in-first-time/51328346#51328346)

The Kalman filter implementation of opencv doesn't let you set an initial state.  This is not intuitive and the lack of documentation makes things even worse.

The way to circumvent this problem is to override the `kalman.correct` and `kalman.predict` methods. You set an initial value of the variable you want to work with and every time you call correct, you first subtract the initial value.  When you call predict, you have to add the initial value.

I have an implementation example here where the Kalman filter is used in an visual tracking problem (tracking car chased by police): 
https://github.com/fredguth/unb-cv-3183/blob/master/p6/r4.py

Comment: Thats really odd. But I was passing initial state to it. Do you say that those initial states which I am passing are all useless ? Also, in your implementation, are you passing your initial states from a file ? Thanks.

Comment: Even if the initial state is zero or some other random thing, I should still be able to track properly right ?

Comment: The initial state you were passing is useless. In my example, the initial state is the Ground Truth in frame zero.

Comment: @JeruLuke Thanks for fixing the typos there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a loop to get rid of the offset.
It may affect the estimator though.
Probably, not a good way to handle the initial offset.

```
Mat_<float> measurement(2, 1);

KF.statePre.at<float> (0) = curMeasurement.x;
KF.statePre.at<float> (1) = curMeasurement.y;
KF.statePre.at<float> (2) = 0;
KF.statePre.at<float> (3) = 0;

measurement(0) = curMeasurement.x;
measurement(1) = curMeasurement.y;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  KF.predict();
  KF.correct(measurement);
}
```