# KalmanFilter always predict 0,0 in first time

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, kalman-filter

The following code use to scan image from bottom to top. However, the prediction of Kalman filter always show 0,0 in first time. So that, it will draw line from bottom to 0,0. How to make path(Kalman filter) more similar to actual path?

The following code and image was updated.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('IMG_4614.jpg',1)
img = cv2.resize(img, (600, 800))
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
low_yellow = np.array([18, 94, 140])
up_yellow = np.array([48, 255, 255])
hsv_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, low_yellow, up_yellow)
hls_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
low_yellow = np.array([0, 170, 24])
up_yellow = np.array([54, 255, 255])
hls_mask = cv2.inRange(hls_image, low_yellow, up_yellow)
mask = np.logical_or(hsv_mask,hls_mask)

offset = 100
height, width, _ = img.shape
previousPos = h
currentPos = h - offset
finalImg = img.copy()
is_first = True

initState = np.array([[np.float32(int(width/2))], [np.float32(h)]], np.float32)
last_measurement = current_measurement = initState
last_prediction = current_prediction = np.array((2, 1), np.float32)
kalman = cv2.KalmanFilter(4, 2)
kalman.measurementMatrix = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]], np.float32)
kalman.transitionMatrix = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)


while currentPos >= 0:
    histogram = np.sum(mask[currentPos:previousPos,:], axis=0)
    areas = np.where(histogram > 40)
    if areas[0].size >= 2:
        bottomLeft = areas[0][0]
        topRight = areas[0][-1]

        x = int((topRight-bottomLeft) / 2 + bottomLeft)
        y = int((previousPos - currentPos) / 2 + currentPos)
        last_prediction = current_prediction
        last_measurement = current_measurement 
        current_measurement = np.array([[np.float32(x)], [np.float32(y)]], np.float32)
        lmx, lmy = last_measurement[0], last_measurement[1]
        cmx, cmy = current_measurement[0], current_measurement[1]

        cv2.rectangle(finalImg, (bottomLeft,previousPos), (topRight,currentPos), (0,255,0), 5)
        cv2.circle(finalImg,(x,y), 5, (0,0,255), -1)
        cv2.line(finalImg, (lmx, lmy), (cmx, cmy), (255, 0, 0),5) #actual path




        kalman.correct(current_measurement-initState)
        current_prediction = kalman.predict()

        lpx, lpy = last_prediction[0] + initState[0], last_prediction[1] + initState[1]
        cpx, cpy = current_prediction[0] + initState[0], current_prediction[1] + initState[1]
        cv2.line(finalImg, (lpx, lpy), (cpx, cpy), (255, 0, 255),5) # predict path  



        plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))  
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(finalImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        plt.show()


    previousPos = currentPos
    currentPos = currentPos - offset
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has already been answered here: 
[Kalman filter always predicting origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863397/kalman-filter-always-predicting-origin/50868636#50868636)

OpenCV Kalman filter implementation does not let you set the an initial state.
You have to save your initial state and then when you call `kalman.correct` you have to subtract the initial state. And when you call `kalman.predict` you have to add your initial state.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
initialState = (y,x)
....

kalman.correct(current_measurement - initialState)
...
prediction = kalman.predict()
prediction[0] = prediction[0] + initState[0]
prediction[1] = prediction[1] + initState[1]
```

Comment: If you post your complete code somewhere (and assets like images), I can try fix your code.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean getMeasurement(...)

Comment: I changed the pseudo-code.  See if you understand this way.

Comment: I really don't know how to implement it. The above code was updated. Could you help me to fix it? Thank you

Comment: ok, I fixed by myself. However, is that possible to do the prediction without measurement? That is, the program can find path automatically after the first time measurement.

Comment: No. The idea of the kalman filter is that in time 1 it predicts a state, in time 2 you measure the reality and then call kalman.correct. In correct(), Kalman will then see how it assumptions were wrong and reweight the filter accordingly.  So, it is absolutely necessary to correct the filter as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change the initial state by changing statePost and statePre. 
In init:

```
self.KF = cv2.KalmanFilter(nmbStateVars, nmbMeasts, nmbControlInputs)

A = self.KF.statePost
A[0:4] = self.measurement.reshape((4, 1))
# A[4:8] = 0.0
self.KF.statePost = A
self.KF.statePre = A
```

Then update as usual

```
self.updatedMeasts = self.KF.correct(self.measurement)
```